# Chromium and Silverlight (Delphi)?

Tags: silverlight, delphi, delphi-6, tchromium

Has anyone ever tried integrating Silverlight with Chromium?  If so, do you know of a document listing the steps to make it work?  I'm using Delphi 6 and the TChromium component.

Comment: I don't think it is wise to mix and match 10 year old technology with state of the art stuff and expect it to become a found and stable solution. In this particular case, TChromium does not support Delph 6. http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of NPAPI and registry settings:

- [Chromium Policy List](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3)
- [NPAPI Plugins](http://src.chromium.org/svn/branches/375/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/npapi.html)
- [Chrome Frame Source](http://src.chromium.org/svn/releases/4.0.259.0/src/chrome_frame/)
- [Chrome Frame Standalone Installer](http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/GoogleChromeframeStandaloneEnterprise.msi)